# How does "unaccept" work?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

I recently found a -15 drop in my reputation because of an "unaccept". What does that mean?
Does it only mean my answer was accepted (+15) and then the acceptance was revoked, so the reputation was taken away (hence the -15)?
Or did I lose 15 more points? (If that is the case, why?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question asker decided to move the checkmark from your answer to somebody else's. This revokes the +15 reputation from the accept checkmark.

The −15 from the unaccepted canceled the +15 you originally got for the accept, so it's as if it never existed in the first place. You didn't lose any further reputation :)

Comment: Or just decided to remove the checkmark altogether. Same effect in the end, though